# Blazor Reference @model.Field with string value

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm using Blazor and I'm not sure how to explain what I'm trying to do.
I got the following Code:

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-sm small">
        <tr>
            @foreach (var property in properties.GetProperties().ToList())
            {
                <th>@property.Name</th>
            }
        </tr>
        @foreach (var report in ReportsList)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var property in properties.GetProperties().ToList())
                {
                    <td>
                        <div class="border-0">
                            @report. @property.Name
                        </div>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>




@code {
    public List<ReportsListModel> ReportsList { get; set; }
    private Type properties { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ReportsList = new List<ReportsListModel>();
        ReportsList = _data.GetReportList();
        properties = typeof(ReportsListModel);
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to Reference **@report.FromDate** by combining **@report.** as string value and concat the value of **@property.Name.** to it and the convert it to reference.
But I'm not sure how to convert a string value into reference.

In other word String.Concat("@report.",@property.Name) should return the same as value as  @report.FromDate in Blazor.

Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @Brout : do you mean you need a variable holding  String.Concat("@report.",@property.Name) to use it twice ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you're looking for is the property value for the specific report.  If so here's a single page working version of your code with a made up `ReportsListModel`.  It uses Reflection by passing the `PropertyInfo` object an instance of the class to get the value.

```
@page "/Reports"
<h3>Reports</h3>

<div>
    <table class="table table-sm small">
        <tr>
            @foreach (var property in properties.GetProperties().ToList())
            {
                <th>@property.Name</th>
            }
        </tr>
        @foreach (var report in ReportsList)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var property in properties.GetProperties().ToList())
                {
                    <td>
                        <div class="border-0">
                                @property.GetValue(report)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>




@code {
    public List<ReportsListModel> ReportsList { get; set; }
    private Type properties { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ReportsList = new List<ReportsListModel>
        {
            new ReportsListModel { Name= "Report1", Value="My Report" },
            new ReportsListModel { Name= "Report2", Value="Fred's Report" }
        };
        properties = typeof(ReportsListModel);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class ReportsListModel
    {
        public Guid GUID { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

    }
```